# API automation for a android App

Tags: api-testing, mobile-automation, rest-api, api, android-automation

I have to start API automation for a android App. App is coded in C++. Please suggest the approach as I am new to API testing.

Comment: Hey I wrote on blog about this query. Hope it will help you in many ways. [Different Approaches to Comprehensive Mobile Testing for iOS and Android Apps](http://17%20Different%20Approaches%20to%20Comprehensive%20Mobile%20Testing%20for%20iOS%20and%20Android%20Apps) I hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REST Assured or Apache HTTP CLIENT for automating any Rest Based Web-Services. 
I don't think that it will matter too much in which language the app is coded.
If you are able to access the service URL's and endpoint you can use either of the above approaches to automate that.

Comment: Hello Saurabh, Thanks for your reply. I am clear about the language part now. Also as I am very new to api testing, can you please let me know what did you mean by "access the service URL's and the endpoint". Do i need to get any URL's or anything from developers?

Comment: Yes Nikhil 
There should be some set or urls for accessing the different services.There should be some Base urls for different services and accessing different methods there should be some differene complete URI. Devlopers should be very easily able to provide you those URL's. You can check with them and you can have a brief idea what each service and end point url must be doing

Comment: There will be url's for android application also?? Please don't mind if the questions are silly. It is just that I am new to this, and I need to start my work asap. And also the tools REST Assured/Apache HTTP CLIENT. Anyone one of these I can use for my android app API automation testing right?

Comment: That's totally fine .. Suppose Your android app is a frontend it must be getting data from any sever and your services are responsible for getting that data from server to your app. same set of services can be used for many no of frontends like andriod app or ios app . and yes you can use any of the tools but REST ASSURED is most commonly used and very easy to understand.
Below is the link for rest assured tutorial its very easy to understand and work:-http://toolsqa.com/rest-assured/configure-eclipse-with-rest-assured/

Comment: Sure Nikhil 
If you feel this is usefull click "This answer was usefull on the post"